# C# version control dll / api

Tags: c#, api, version-control, dll

I'm trying to find a version control Dll / Api that I can link/reference in my project without having to install a SVN of some kind.

I've been trying all afternoon to get libgit2sharp to work, but am having problems with it.  That'll be another question, but in the meantime, anyone have other suggestions?

By the way, GitSharp is on hold and they suggested libgit2sharp as a replacement, so GitSharp isn't an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be willing to take a look at **[Witinyki](https://www.github.com/nulltoken/witinyki)**.

It's a very simple wiki web application built with ASP.Net MVC 3 and leveraging **[LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp)** as its storage backend.

Please note that it's still in its very early stages. However, it should provide you with some help (at least, I hope so :-) ).

Comment: Thanks nulltoken.  I ended up writing my own svn, since I wanted hard access to the svn and file (aka not wanting to do checkouts).  For example:  `repo["products/dishsoap"].Head.Text` would result in the most current version of the text for the file `products/dishsoap` - no checkout required.

Comment: LibGit2Sharp also allows one to retrieve the content of a file without checking it out first. However the current syntax to do so is less terse than yours. Beware, I may shamelessly get some inspiration from it :)

Comment: `repo[].Head` is a shortcut for `repo[].History.Head` which is a shortcut for `repo.XmlFiles[].History.Head`.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/ is an API available for Subversion- I don't believe that you need to install a Subversion client to use it.

This presupposes of course that SVN is an acceptable version control system for your purposes.

Comment: I'm creating a wiki controller, so what would you recommend as a VCS?

Comment: Subversion would be a good VCS in this case.  I was worried that you were doing something like an occasionally-connected application, where a DVCS like Git or Mercurial would serve multiple users making disconnected edits more efficiently.  Since your app will presumably always be connected to the VCS, SVN will probably work well.

Comment: Can you check out individual files with SharpSVN without having to save them to a file?  99% of the time a file would be checked out to just get its text to display and I wouldn't want to have to create a temp file for it.  Nor would I want to have to create a file to 'edit' and then check in.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt look like it: http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/Overload_SharpSvn_SvnClient_CheckOut.htm