# What HTTP Protocols does GIT use when cloning and pushing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to use the LibGit2Sharp library resond to basic GIT commands such as clone and push with ASP.MVC and not sure how i should set up my controllers to respond accordingly.

Does GIT initiate a HTTP GET and POST request when cloning pushing?  And should my controllers be set up like

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Clone(string path)
{
  //Return repo as stream?
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Push(string path)
{
  //Commit to repo
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the source and see what is actually done, though I expect it shouldn't matter, or look at the first answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313155/c-sharp-version-control-dll-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you're trying to code something similar to git-daemon.
Unfortunately, LibGit2Sharp doesn't implement network-related features yet.

Thus, it's not possible to serve `push`, `pull`, `clone` or `fetch` requests from ASP.Net MVC yet.

[@synhershko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135701/synhershko) 's issue in LibGit2Sharp tracker deals with a related subject: **[Proper pull, fetch, merge support](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/65)**

**EDIT:**
If you wish to get a better understanding about Git transfer protocols from an HTTP perspective, I'd warmly recommend the following resources to start with:

- [Pro Git - Transfer Protocols](http://progit.org/book/ch9-6.html)
- [Smart HTTP Transport](http://progit.org/2010/03/04/smart-http.html)

Then, I'm afraid you'll have to dig into the code in order to get a better grasp of how it "works". My experience is that starting with JGit (java reimplementation of Git) code is a bit easier than a straight dive into the original Git C code. You'll find JGit transport related code **[here](http://egit.eclipse.org/w/?p=jgit.git;a=tree;f=org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport;h=4e36b8807fa1c0f1af6d50dd2d746f58c101e25c;hb=HEAD)**.

Comment: Well if i understand what is sent down the wire then possibly MVC can be the network interface into LibGit2Sharp.  I don't see why LibGit2Sharp needs network related features when all it needs to deal with is local disk repositories?

Comment: @Fixer *Well if i understand what is sent down the wire* -> I've updated my answer with some links to network protocol related documentation and code. *I don't see why LibGit2Sharp needs network related features* -> LibGit2Sharp is a binding on top of libgit2. And the scope of libgit2 goes beyond local repositories ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, should be useful.  Yeah sorry for the lack of info, my app is using LibGit2 for local repos only.  And the MVC app will be the interface into and out of other repos.